# Access local variable within inner class defined inside func

Tags: swift

I've created a unit test helper function, but I'm failing to see how to access the locally scoped input parameter within the inner class inside the function:

I want to access 'error' inside the inner MockRentalsService class

```
func rentalsServiceWhichThrowsError(error: RentalError) -> Rentals {
    class MockRentalsService: Rentals {
        func rentalList(completionHandler:(rentalListResponse:RentalListResponse) -> Void ) -> RentalListCached {
            completionHandler(rentalListResponse: RentalListResponse.Error(error))
            return nil
        }
    }
    let rentalsService = MockRentalsService()
    return rentalsService
}
```

The swift compiler doesn't like this at all - and just gives me a Segmentation fault 11

Comment: A compiler crash is always a bug, no matter how right or wrong the code is

Comment: Well, I've logged the bug on radar. But the code is wrong too - however I want the compiler to tell me why it's wrong. But what i want from here is another way to access the local var within the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it at the moment, which is a bit of a kludge - but it works.

```
func rentalsServiceWhichThrowsError(error: RentalError) -> Rentals {
class MockRentalsService: Rentals {
    var rentalError: RentalError!
    func rentalList(completionHandler:(rentalListResponse:RentalListResponse) -> Void ) -> RentalListCached {
        completionHandler(rentalListResponse: RentalListResponse.Error(rentalError))
        return nil
    }
}
let rentalsService = MockRentalsService()
rentalService.rentalError = error
return rentalsService
```

}